# nodejs socket.io - connected to server but emit doesn't do anything

Tags: node.js, sockets, express, socket.io

I'm starting to work with `Socket.io` and my `nodeJS API`

I succeeded to get my user connected, and showed a message on my server.

But now, I'm trying to send data to my client -> then server -> then client again etc.

But when I use `emit` nothing appends... So this i my code :

**`SERVER SIDE`**

```
    io.on('connection', function(socket){
      console.log("user connected") // I see that
      socket.emit('text', 'it works!'); //

      socket.on('test1', function (data) {
        console.log('received 1 : ');  //  Never showed 
        console.log(data); // Never showed
      });

     }
```

**`CLIENT SIDE`**

```
    var socket = io.connect(myUrl); // good connection

    socket.emit ('test1', {map: 4, coords: '0.0'}); // never showed on the server side


    socket.on('text', function(text) {
      alert(text);  // never showed
     socket.emit('test', { "test": "test2" });
    });
```

Any ideas?

thanks !

Comment: any errors on the console?

Comment: nothing showed in the console

Comment: Please put the code in your question back the way it was when you first posted.  When you change the code you originally posted, you change the question to a new and different question rendering the answers received so far completely out of context.  That is NOT how this site is supposed to work.  If you need to communicate additional code, then you can add it afterwards.  In this particular case, you don't need to show the code you tried as that is already covered in the answer.  You can just add a comment that you tried the suggestion and explain what you observed.

Comment: I think you could be missing " ; " after console.log("user connected") . Try adding the " ; " and see if it works.

Comment: rollback the edit - the missing ';'  is not changing anything

Comment: What exactly is the value of `myUrl`.  Are you by any chance connection to a namespace?

Comment: Try to send messages in `setInterval`, to be sure that connection delay is not a problem

Comment: myUrl is `localhost:8080` here
is it really a good idea to send it in a `setInterval`?

Comment: Did you find the problem?
I am facing the same problem here

Comment: Same issue here, tried it in many environments with React and Electron

Comment: @F4Ke i bet you fixed this already.. how did you do it.. I am facing this currently

Answer (score 0):

Your Starter Code seems to be valid, you need to check two things :

- if you successfully included the `socket.min.js` in the client side
- if you re having any error printed in the console

Comment: The connection to the server socket is working, this in just the emit that won't work

Comment: can you do me a favor and replace the alert with an innocent console.log ?

Comment: still nothing appears

Comment: wow that is weirdly weird ! can i take a look at your express.js code ?

Comment: You have it 'server side' there's nothing important except that

Answer (score 0):

On the client side, you have to wait until the connection succeeds before it is safe to send data to the server.  Connecting to the server is not synchronous or instantaneous (thus it is not ready immediately).  You are trying to send data before the connection is ready.

Put your first send of data inside a `socket.on('connect', ...)` handler.

```
var socket = io.connect(myUrl); // good connection

// send some data as soon as we are connected
socket.on('connect', function() {
    socket.emit ('test1', {map: 4, coords: '0.0'});
});


socket.on('text', function(text) {
  alert(text);  // never showed
 socket.emit('test', { "test": "test2" });
});
```

Comment: I've edited my post following your instructions, but nothing changes :(

Comment: @F4Ke -  First, you need to examine your console on client and server to make sure there are no errors.  Then, you will need to examine the network tab in the browser debugger to see if everything is being sent and received as expected.

Comment: @F4Ke - And, please DO NOT EDIT the original code in your question.  That changes the question from what you originally asked and renders answers offered so far meaningless which is not how this site should work.  If you need to show additional code, add it to the end of your question.  In this case, you don't need to edit your question at all. A comment is enough.

Comment: the console is clean, the network seems only requests with code 200

Comment: @F4Ke - In the network tab, did you drill into the individual webSocket packets and see what was being sent both ways?

Comment: @jfriend00 #offtop [had same case, OP drastically changed question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/37121872/revisions), how we can handle such things? I see it can be rolled back, but don't think it's a good idea

Comment: @MedetTleukabiluly - I usually just explain to the OP why they should not change the question to a whole new question and advise that they should restore the content that was previously there and they nearly always do (as they did in this case).  It's a matter of teaching them how stack overflow is supposed to work.

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me

**CLIENT SIDE**

```
//sending custom data to server after successful connection
socket.on('connect', function(){
           this.socket.emit('client-to-server', {map: 4, coords: '0.0'});
        });
//listening the event fired by the socket server
socket.on('server-to-client', function(dataSendbyTheServer){
            // do whatever you want
               console.log(dataSendbyTheServer);
        });
```

**SERVER SIDE**

```
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
// listening the event fired by the client
socket.on('client-to-server', function (data) {
    console.log('received 1 : ');
    // sending back to client
    io.emit('server-to-client', data)
 });
});
```